# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_all_subjects() in

Tags: php

I am trying to teach myself PHP & MySQL. Please note I am very new to this. Below is the error message I am getting and all the code.

I hope this makes sense!!!

Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_all_subjects() in /Users/darren/Sites/widget_corp/content.php on line 9

***content.php code***

```
<?php require_once("includes/connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
<table id="structure">
<tr>
<td id="navigation">
<ul class="subjects">
<?php
$subject_set = get_all_subjects(); **// this is the problem line**
while ($subject = mysql_fetch_array($subject_set)) {
echo "<li><a href=\"content.php?subj=" . urlencode($subject["id"]) . 
    "\">{$subject["menu_name"]}</a></li>";
$page_set = get_pages_for_subject($subject["id"]);
echo "<ul class=\"pages\">";
while ($page = mysql_fetch_array($page_set)) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"content.php?page=" . urlencode($page["id"]) .
        "\">{$page["menu_name"]}</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
}

?>
</ul>
</td>
<td id="page">
<h2>Content Area</h2>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php require("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

***This is my functions code*** it resides in a folder called "includes"

```
</php
// This is where we store all the basic functions

function confirm_query($result_set) {
if (!$result_set) {
die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}       
}

function get_all_subjects() {
global $connection;
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM subjects 
ORDER BY position ASC";
$subject_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
confirm_query($subject_set);
return $subject_set;
}

function get_pages_for_subject($subject_id) {
global $connection;
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM pages 
WHERE subject_id = {$subject_id"} 
ORDER BY position ASC";             
$page_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
confirm_query($page_set);
return $page_set;   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Your functions code has a mal-formed opening `<?php` tag - you've got `</php`. Without that opening tag, PHP will process the file as plaintext and never treat it as PHP code. This means your function never got defined.

Remember that there is not such things as a "PHP script". There are only text files that happen to contain PHP code blocks. The opening `<?PHP` tag is REQUIRED at some point in the file, otherwise your 'code' just text.